# Inconsistent parameter pack deduction int and int& in variadic templated member function that creates a thread that runs a member function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'm getting an inconsistent parameter pack compiler error when I try to run this toy example. Could someone shed light on why 'int a' is being deduced as an int& here? In the example below, when I run the 'test' function below with an int literal it works fine. Thanks in advance for the explanation!

```
class Test {
    public:
    Test() {}

    ~Test() {
        t.join();
     }

    void print(int num)
    {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    }

    template<class ...Args>
    void test(void(Test::*b)(Args...) , Args&&... args)
    {
        t = std::thread(b, this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    std::thread t;
    };

int main()
{
    int a = 123;
    Test test;
    test.test(&Test::print, a);
    // test.test(&Test::print, 123); works
}
```

Error:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:82:40: error: no matching function for call to 'Test::test( 
void (Test::*)(int), int&)'
     test.test(&Test::print, a);
                               ^     
prog.cc:82:40: note: candidate is:
prog.cc:62:10: note: template<class ... Args> void Test::test(void 
(Test::*)(Args ...), Args&& ...)
     void test(void(Test::*b)(Args...) , Args&&... args)
      ^
prog.cc:62:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:82:40: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'int' and 
'int&'
     test.test(&Test::print, a);
                               ^
```

Comment: What is `printThree`?

Comment: @Sergey typo-- fixed. sorry.

Comment: You are using perfect forwarding. The whole point of that is to preserve the value category of the argument - to deduce lvalue reference type for an lvalue argument, and an rvalue reference type for an rvalue argument. Looks like it's doing its job, well, perfectly.

Comment: Is the error message from an old version of the code?  It talks about a `char` parameter to `Test::test`.

Answer (score 6):

Never use deduced forward reference types to exactly match other arguments.

Perfect forwarded `Args` when you pass an lvalue `int` deduces `Args` to be `int&`.  Then `int& &&` collapses into `int&`.

In short, **Never use deduced forward reference types to exactly match other arguments**.

There are rare exceptions, but that is inside library-style code where one type was already deduced from another in an earlier context.

This:

```
template<class ...Args>
void test(void(Test::*b)(Args...) , Args&&... args)
{
    t = std::thread(b, this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

is constrained.

Try:

```
template<class F, class ...Args>
void test(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    t = std::thread(std::forward<F>(f), this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

what exactly the first arg is is not your problem.  It could be a member function pointer to `this`, it could be an object that can take `this` as its first argument.

If for whatever reason you want to insist that the first argument be a member function pointer:

```
template<class R, class...A0s, class ...Args>
void test(R(Test::*f)(A0s...), Args&&... args)
{
    t = std::thread(f, this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

don't over-constrain it.  If you really really want to ensure that the error happens at invokation of `test` instead of within its body, we can do:

```
template<class R, class...A0s, class ...Args>
auto test(R(Test::*f)(A0s...), Args&&... args)
-> decltype((void)((std::declval<Test*>()->*f)(std::declval<typename std::decay<Args>::type>()...) )>
{
    t = std::thread(f, this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

where we SFINAE disable this based on being able to invoke `this->*f` with decayed copies of `args...`.

This is usually overkill.

Finally, we can do this:

```
template<class T> struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class T> using no_deduction=typename tag_t<T>::type;

template<class ...Args>
void test(void(Test::*b)(Args...) , no_deduction<Args>... args)
{
    t = std::thread(b, this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

where we block deduction on the arguments, and only pattern match on the function pointer.  This doesn't work if `b` wants to take a reference; we'd require some extra type programming to morph `T&` into `std::reference_wrapper<T>`:

```
template<class T>
struct compatible_arg { using type=T; };
template<class T>
struct compatible_arg<T&> {
  using type=std::reference_wrapper<T>;
};
template<class T>
using compatible_arg_t = typename compatible_arg<T>::type;

template<class ...Args>
void test(void(Test::*b)(Args...) , compatible_arg_t<Args>... args)
{
    t = std::thread(b, this, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}
```

which maps `T&&` to `T&&`, `T` to `T` and `T&` to `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.

But really, just stop at:

```
template<class F, class ...Args>
void test(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    t = std::thread(std::forward<F>(f), this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: I think you may have duplicated your first sentence

Comment: `std::result_of` is deprecated. Use [std::invoke_result](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) instead.

Comment: @mario in [tag:C++11]?

Comment: @Yakk, no, but you were using `std::void_t` in the answer, so I assumed C++17.

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class ...Args>
void test(void(Test::*b)(Args...) , Args&&... args)
{
    t = std::thread(b, this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

When you do something like this, it means:

- Deduce `Args...` from the PMF passed as the first argument.
- Then deduce `Args...` independently from the type and value categories of the remaining arguments.
- The results of the two independent deductions must match, otherwise it's an error.

This is virtually *never* what you actually want to do. There's often no exact-match relation between the type of a function's parameter and the type and value category of its corresponding argument.

Here, you don't actually need the PMF's argument type (not to mention that you would have to write a gazillion overloads to cover all possible combinations of cv- and ref-qualifiers), so you can restrict it to "pointer to member of `Test` of some type":

```
template<class F, class... Args>
void test(F Test::* b, Args&&... args)
{
    t = std::thread(b, this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Or simply leave it unconstrained:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
void test(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    t = std::thread(std::forward<F>(f), this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Alternatively, you can introduce a new pack:

```
template<class ...Args, class... Args2>
void test(void(Test::*b)(Args...) , Args2&&... args)
{
    t = std::thread(b, this, std::forward<Args2>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. For the third example where you introduce a new pack, does the first pack(Args) get deduced based on b's function signature?